# Unknown segue relationship: Prototype with NSCollectionView

Tags: storyboard, swift, nscollectionview, xcode6

Just by adding an NSCollectionView to Storyboard, the code won't compile with the error: **Unknown segue relationship: Prototype**.

Is this a known bug of Swift/XCode6-beta4 or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried it with beta 5?

Comment: I got the same problem almost a year later with Xcode 7 Beta 1.

Comment: Still happening in Xcode 7 beta 3

Comment: .. and still happening in Xcode 7.1 :(

Comment: STILL an issue on xcode 7.3 beta 4 7D152p.  This is absolutely insane

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug, and is mentioned (with a workaround) in the [release notes of Xcode 6 beta-5](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_5_za4gu6/xcode_6_beta_5__release_notes_.pdf):

> A storyboard may fail to compile after adding an NSCollectionView to
> it. (17009377)!
>
> Workaround: Pick a xib that includes the NSCollectionView and load it
> into a Storyboard based View.!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't read that. Hopefully it will get definitely fixed in the next beta.

Answer (score 6):

**Update for Xcode 7 beta 6 ([see release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_3/Xcode_7_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf)):**

Interface Builder supports the new NSCollectionView API in 10.11, using dataSource and layouts like on iOS. (18997303)

- Workaround: It is not possible to configure prototype items in Interface Builder. Use -[NSCollectionView registerClass:forItemWithIdentifier:] or -[NSCollectionView registerNib:forItemWithIdentifier:] in code.

Has anyone tried to work with it before? Should I just add an empty collection view to my story board, then create a nib file just for the collectionviewitem and finally link it via code?

---

Update for Xcode 7.1 beta 3

I've downloaded and tested the new beta today and the problem is still there. However they have strangely removed the workaround notes from the [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.1_beta_3/Xcode_7.1_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf) as if they had fixed it...

Comment: still in Version 7.2 (7C68) :(

Answer (score 5):

There's actually no need to create an extra XIB file when you are already using storyboards.

1. Remove the connection between the `NSCollectionView` and the `NSCollectionViewItem`
2. Give the view item an identifier
3. Set the item prototype programmatically in your surrounding `NSViewController`:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.collectionView.itemPrototype = self.storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("collectionViewItem")
        as NSCollectionViewItem
}
```

This keeps all UI views in one place and thus provides a nicer workaround than having an alien XIB file hanging around.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for that. It's so weird that this works (it does, confirmed) given the method name that involves the word "Controller" (how is that item a controller? would have expected that method to only return objects of type NSViewController for instance, if I was to guess).

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I spoke too soon, didn't notice an assertion failure. The documentation now suggests not setting the item prototype property anymore actually (when using the 10.11 SDK anyway).

Comment: Right. When you're targeting earlier OS X versions before 10.11 this is however still a nicer workaround instead of creating an extra XIB file.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using the OSX 10.11 SDK, the following info from [Apple's release notes for it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_11CollectionView) instructs not populating the `itemPrototype` property at all anymore (that of course assumes your minimum deployment target is 10.11):

> To use NSCollectionView’s new API model, you specify a layout by setting an NSCollectionView’s “collectionViewLayout” property, and either provide a “dataSource” or bind your CollectionView’s “content” to an NSArray or NSArrayController (see “Binding Content to an NSCollectionView”, below). You must also disconnect and discard the NSCollectionView’s “itemPrototype”, which is a vestige of the 10.10-and-earlier API model.